# difference between the colum values across rows

Tags: r, dplyr

With a dataframe like below

```
text <- "
location_id,brand,count,driven_km,efficiency,mileage,age
23040204995,Toyota,8,2761,0.57,333,2.17
23040204995,Honda,23,2307,0.38,117.5,0.45
23040204995,Tesla,16,3578,0.65,127,0.38
23040204996,Toyota,16,3578,0.65,127,0.38
23040204996,Nissan,38,2504,0.37,563.5,0.74
23040204996,Tesla,24,892,0.32,175,0.48
23040204997,Tesla,11,1879.5,0.67,298.5,0.57
23040204998,Honda,24,892,0.32,175,0.48
"
df <- read.table(textConnection(text), sep=",", header = T)
```

For each `location_id` I need to compute the diff of the values `count,driven_km,efficiency,mileage,age` for all the brands from the value for `Tesla`.  The different need to computed such that the `Value for i - Value for Tesla` where `i={"Toyota", "Honda", "Nissan" ..}`. There are `location_id`s where values `Tesla` may not be present or only value for `Tesla` may be present, they need to be ignored as the diff doesn't make sense for those `location_id`s.

I'm looking for an elegant way of doing this - preferably in `dplyr` way.

expected output

```
location_id,brand,count,driven_km,efficiency,mileage,age
23040204995,Toyota,-8,-817,-0.08,206,1.79
23040204995,Honda,7,-1271,-0.27,-9.5,0.07
23040204996,Toyota,-8,2686,0.33,-48,-0.1
23040204996,Nissan,14,1612,0.05,388.5,0.26
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `data.table`, grouped by 'location_id', we specify the columns to diff in `.SDcols`, get the difference by looping through the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x[brand != "Tesla"] - 
      x[brand == "Tesla"]), location_id, .SDcols = count:age]
```

---

If the corresponding 'brand' column is also needed

```
setDT(df)[, c(list(brand = brand), lapply(.SD, function(x) if("Tesla" %in% brand) 
   as.numeric(x - x[brand == "Tesla"]) else NA_real_)), location_id, .SDcols = count:age
      ][brand != "Tesla" & !is.na(count)]
#  location_id  brand count driven_km efficiency mileage   age
#1: 23040204995 Toyota    -8      -817      -0.08   206.0  1.79
#2: 23040204995  Honda     7     -1271      -0.27    -9.5  0.07
#3: 23040204996 Toyota    -8      2686       0.33   -48.0 -0.10
#4: 23040204996 Nissan    14      1612       0.05   388.5  0.26
```

---

Or if we use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gather(df, key, val, count:age) %>%
   group_by(location_id, key) %>%
   filter("Toyota" %in% brand) %>% 
   mutate(val = val- val[brand == "Tesla"]) %>% 
   filter(brand != "Tesla") %>% 
   ungroup %>%
   mutate_at(vars(brand, key), funs(factor(., levels = unique(.)))) %>% 
   spread(key, val)
# A tibble: 4 x 7
#  location_id brand   count driven_km efficiency mileage     age
#*       <dbl> <fctr>  <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 23040204995 Toyota - 8.00     - 817    -0.0800  206     1.79  
#2 23040204995 Honda    7.00     -1271    -0.270  -  9.50  0.0700
#3 23040204996 Toyota - 8.00      2686     0.330  - 48.0  -0.100 
#4 23040204996 Nissan  14.0       1612     0.0500  388     0.260
```

Comment: interesting tidyverse is very similar to my suggestion.  what does `filter("Toyota" %in% brand)` do?

Comment: @bdecaf I used `gather/spread` similar to yours, but yours is with `inner_join` which I didn't do.  The `filter` is to keep only those groups that have 'Toyota' in 'brand' column

Comment: I see - I like how your answer maintains the ordering. Is it `mutate_at(vars(brand, key), funs(factor(., levels = unique(.))))` that achieves this?

Comment: @bdecaf  Yes, the `spread` will reorder it alphabetic order.  Inorder to avoid that, I did the factor way.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

So I'd do it via `tidyr` to make it `dplyr` like.

```
library(tidyr)

dfl <- gather(df, "key", "value", -location_id, -brand)
dflt <- dfl %>% filter(brand == "Tesla")
dfln <- dfl %>% filter(brand != "Tesla")

inner_join(dflt,  dfln, by = c("location_id", "key")) %>% 
    mutate(value = value.y - value.x) %>% 
    select(location_id, brand = brand.y, key, value) %>% 
    spread(key,value)

#   location_id  brand   age count driven_km efficiency mileage
# 1 23040204995  Honda  0.07     7     -1271      -0.27    -9.5
# 2 23040204995 Toyota  1.79    -8      -817      -0.08   206.0
# 3 23040204996 Nissan  0.26    14      1612       0.05   388.5
# 4 23040204996 Toyota -0.10    -8      2686       0.33   -48.0
```

ordering of columns is different - but you can rearrange them.